# Disable javascript script at a certain screen width

Tags: javascript, svg, mobile, responsive-design

Is it possible to write a script that turns off a script at a certain screen resolution? I have these svg's that do not work properly under 480px, and I would like to turn them off. I am super new to this. Any help would be amazing.

```
<script>
        (function() {

            function init() {
                var speed = 250,
                    easing = mina.easeinout;

                [].slice.call ( document.querySelectorAll( '#grid > .container > .row .activities_home > a' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
                    var s = Snap( el.querySelector( 'svg' ) ), path = s.select( 'path' ),
                        pathConfig = {
                            from : path.attr( 'd' ),
                            to : el.getAttribute( 'data-path-hover' )
                        };

                    el.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', function() {
                        path.animate( { 'path' : pathConfig.to }, speed, easing );
                    } );

                    el.addEventListener( 'mouseleave', function() {
                        path.animate( { 'path' : pathConfig.from }, speed, easing );
                    } );
                } );
            }



            init();

        })();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach an event listener to the document `DOMContentLoaded` and window `resize` events to query the screen resolution (the `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` properties).

If the resolution falls below your breakpoint, then you can remove the event listeners from each of the paths (you will need a reference to the function in order to do so).

If you don't need to handle resize events and just want to initially disable the script based on the resolution, then you can do something simple like replacing:

```
init();
```

with

```
if (window.innerWidth > 480)
  init();
```